# Create a file format (csv,json,etc) when save/update a Post

Tags: json, xml

I need create a file (any type: json, php, csv, txt) when I create or update a post from WPadmin. The format structure would be:

ID, "operation to execute" (new post, update post, delete post), title, field2, field3

Thanks!
martin

Comment: This seem your first question in this site. Wellcome. To help with your issue it is appreciated that you show us the effort you have done to do it yourself: code, research, etc. Also, you would narrow down the exact problem you have to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of action hooks for [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions). They each receive the `$post` object as an argument. You could use these to trigger a function that writes your file to disk using [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Edit: if you're writing CSV, PHP has a function specifically for that: [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) (`fopen` still required)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the save_post action to perform an action when creating or updating a post

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: Yes, paul. I put this block as function and added the action save_post.

function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {

 (the entire block)
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );

Answer (score 0):

Thanks paul/karpstrucking for your responses!

I tried with this codex example.. for sending fields to my mailbox, but this isnt running... i need little sample for testing when i publish..

i put this block on theme's functions.php.. that is ok?

function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {

```
// If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;

$post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
$post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
$subject = 'A post has been updated';

$message = "A post has been updated on your website:\n\n";
$message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url;

// Send email to admin.
wp_mail( 'admin@example.com', $subject, $message );
```

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' )